# ImageMagick output's page number

Tags: imagemagick, command-prompt

So i have to convert a multipaged pdf to single paged tiff files. Using ImageMagick here's what I have so far

```
convert -density 300 input.pdf -compress group4  output-%d.tiff
```

The output file's name starts with output-0.tiff is there any way to have it start with output-1.tiff instead?

Comment: The command line option `-scene 1` should do the trick. Although Kurt's answer is better in this situation. Via: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#scene

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist to use ImageMagick for PDF->TIFF conversion, you cannot get what you want.

Furthermore, *it is not even ImageMagick which does the conversion itself*, because IM cannot process PDFs directly. It has to call Ghostscript as its *'delegate'* to read the PDFs. (This can be revealed to you if you add `-verbose` as the first parameter to the commandline you used).

Plus, the conversion will be slow: because ImageMagick isn't calling Ghostscript in a way that causes *direct* PDF->TIFF conversion, but it calls Ghostscript to do a PDF->PNG conversion (at **72dpi** !!) first, and then ImageMagick itself does the PNG->TIFF translation (at 300 dpi)...

If you take my advice for PDF->TIFF conversion -- to use Ghostscript directly -- you'll get the best of both worlds:

- you can have the first output page to be named `output-1.tiff` (or `output-0001.tiff`),
- and you can have a faster conversion too.

My Ghostscript commandline would be:

```
gs                    \
  -o output-%03d.tiff \
  -sDEVICE=tiffg4     \
   input.pdf
```

The `tiffg4` output device of Ghostscript by default uses a resolution of 204x196 dpi -- as is the standard for Fax G4 files. To *really* increase quality and resolution of your output to *genuine* 300 dpi, use

```
gs                    \
  -o output-%03d.tiff \
  -sDEVICE=tiffg4     \
  -r300x300           \
   input.pdf
```

or even

```
gs                      \
  -o output2-%03d.tiff  \
  -dAlignToPixels=0     \
  -dGridFitTT=2         \
  -dTextAlphaBits=4     \
  -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 \
  -sDEVICE=tiffg4       \
  -r300x300             \
   input.pdf
```

Comment: changed the ouput to -o output2-%01d.tiff but otherwise this works fantastic thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

you can use `-scene` for start number like:

`convert -density 300 input.pdf -compress group4 -scene 1 output-%d.tiff`

this produce output:

`output-1.tiff
output-2.tiff ... etc`